# Call to graph api fails with inexplicable logs and the socket exception not getting caught

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, socketexception, microsoft-graph-sdks

**Describe the bug**
We are getting intermittent failures when calling graph.microsoft.com. The exception isn't very clear and its been very difficult debugging the issue. I haven't actually been able to reproduce it locally.

Our app is a .net core 2.1 app running on Kubernetes. We try to get user memberships with the following code

```
var memberIds = await graphClient.Me.TransitiveMemberOf.Request(userOptions).GetAsync();
userMemberships = memberIds.Select(o => o.Id).ToList();

while (memberIds.NextPageRequest != null)
{
     memberIds = await memberIds.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
     userMemberships.AddRange(memberIds.Select(o => o.Id).ToList());
}
```

Its not clear from the trace where the error actually is but the lines above are the only ones which we call graph so we tried wrapping this in a try catch:

```
try {
 // get members
} catch(ServiceException e) {
  // log something
}
```

Here is the exception trace:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+<EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<CreateConnectionAsync>d__44.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync>d__49.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<SendWithRetryAsync>d__39.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper+<SendWithAuthAsync>d__17.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler+<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler+<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
Inner exception System.IO.IOException handled at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+<EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsClient (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream+<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__47_0 (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+<EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
Inner exception System.Net.Sockets.SocketException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
```

The exception message

```
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. Connection reset by peer
```

**To Reproduce**
I have not been able to reproduce. I've managed to force a similar exception by blocking graph.microsoft.com on my local machine. This gave me the following:
[click here for screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/15933995/69274383-292bde80-0bd2-11ea-8062-5d9b63162363.png)
This error actually was caught in the try catch so I am baffled as to why the other one didn't.

**Expected behavior**
I expected a  ServiceException  with better explanation of the problem and how to resolve it

**Package Version**
Microsoft.Graph: v1.17.0
Microsoft.Graph.Core: v1.18.0

**Additional context**
I've been reading a little and it may be due to socket starvation. Is there any way I can avoid creating a new Graph service instance every time. I can't find much material which tells me if this is possible. I know that you can do that with a httpclient instance and keep reusing it. I can see there is a GraphClientFactory but nothing on how to use it or if you can reuse it.

Please if you could provide insight it would be great. Thanks

Comment: This normally means your using TLS 1.2. Are you setting `SslProtocols ` to something other than `Tls12` at startup?

Comment: Hi @Marc Thanks for responding no I'm not making any changes in startup. I'm not sure what the default is but I thought TLS 1.2 was recommended though  https://microsoftgraph.github.io/msgraph-sdk-design/GraphClientFactory.html

Comment: hey @SuemayahEldursi were you able to fix this issue? I am experiencing the same thing.

Comment: hey SuemayahEldursi and @vinicius-paiva we are having this same issue for the past week ... any one have any ideas?

Comment: @Albi All our apps had this periodically and we think it was due to the socket exaustion. We mad sure all the apps were using HttpClients correctly to reduce that and also added retries around the area where this was happening.

Comment: Make sure you are creating the GraphServiceClient as a scoped service in Startup.cs. Otherwise a socket exception might be due to it opening a new port on each instance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the Graph API SDK. Without being able to see your Startup.cs, I will go ahead and recommend using dependency injection with the GraphServiceClient:

GraphAPI.cs

```
public class GraphAPI
{
    public static GraphServiceClient Initialize(IConfiguration config)
    {
        return new GraphServiceClient
            (
                new ClientSecretCredential
                (
                    "[TenantID]",
                    "[ClientID]",
                    "[ClientSecret]",
                    new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud }
                ),
                new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }
            );
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    // graph api
    services.AddScoped(svc => GraphAPI.Initialize(Configuration));
    ...
}
```

GraphServiceClient should be able to handle socket instances. If you want more control over this entire workflow, I sugggest moving toward creating your own HttpClient using IHttpClientFactory and calling the Graph REST API directly. This is my prefered way of consuming this API. It increases the performance of the entire app. Instead of throwing an exception the moment anything goes wrong, it just returns an HTTP response code which is much easier and faster on the backend.